# Python Beautiful Soup: Not finding all links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap match data for League of Legends. However, when using this link (https://eu.lolesports.com/en/schedule#slug=all), the match links (with the button: "Show Match") do not show up.

I am using the following code:

```
url = 'https://eu.lolesports.com/en/schedule#slug=na-lcs'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_page = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    link = (a['href'])
    print(link)
```

I would like to find the matchlinks that have this format "/en/lck/lck_2018_spring/match/2018-01-23/bbq-olivers-vs-rox-tigers". But instead I only get links like these:

> http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/legal/privacy
>   https://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/legal/cookie-policy /en/about
>   http://twitch.tv/riotgames http://facebook.com/lolesports
>   http://twitter.com/lolesports http://youtube.com/lolesports
>   http://www.azubu.tv/lolesports http://instagram.com/lolesports
>   http://leagueoflegends.com

Is there something that can be done to change my code so I can get the matchlinks? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do a wget or a curl request against 'https://eu.lolesports.com/en/schedule#slug=na-lcs'.  See whether the content is being generated via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a javascript rendered page. You need to use a webkit library to render the page -> get the html -> scrape the html for links.

This link should be useful: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/